# Jquery / CSS Reset style

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a login window using javascript (JQuery) which complies to very strict design guidelines; it exhaustively uses CSS-floats in order to position the screen elements.
This javascript is hosted from a central location and implemented by ~1000 websites. 
It works very well, but there are some websites that have in their stylesheet something like this:

```
 img, div, input { 
       behavior: url("_include/website/js/iepngfix.htc") 
   }
```

Problem is that such CSS-definitions disturbs the layout of my login window.

My javascript + css are loaded last. Is there a way I can tell in my Javascript / CSS to ignore all styles that have been loaded previously.

Comment: you can try `!important` on the CSS you want to try and force.

Comment: Usage of !important and fcalderan's works. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

Override styles defined in previous style sheets using `!important` property.

**Method 2**

If you are using jQuery in your code then you can clear these attributes on `init()` function. This will add advantage as you can still assign CSS attributes to tags in your CSS files.

```
$('img').css('padding', '0px');
```

*Note: You might try using `iframe` for login page code. I haven't tried this but, I guess this might work.*

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose your window has a container class e.g. *mylogin* then you could try to add in queue the following css

```
.mylogin img,
.mylogin div,
.mylogin input {
   behavior : url(data:null);
}
```